# When is placement final in a splitViewController?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

In viewDidLoad of my master view controller, I see if I'm logged in and if not, call the popover segue to get the login information with the loginButton as the sender.

Setting breakpoint, I see that the button's frame is at 600 for the x origin.  If I hit the button manually (after everything has loaded), it's at 233 for the x origin.  So after ViewDidLoad, there's some other stuff going on that will move the button.

What's the proper place to do the check and pop the login popover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper place for this is in viewDidAppear